# Why IIS localhost very slow loading

Tags: performance, iis, localhost, loading, genexus

Using GeneXusX ev3 U15m, C# (net), Web, Sqlserver.
When change some object and build this, refresh website and wait for long time (more 9 minutes).
Test with move parameters IIS, hosts, web.config, debug off (only release), without firewall, and same.

Comment: Enable FRT and see how the time is consumed on each steps, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis That should get you  started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Have you tried with the tag optimizeCompilations="true" in the web.config?

Original line :

```
<compilation debug="true" strict="false">
```

Change it to:

```
<compilation debug="true" strict="false" optimizeCompilations="true">
```

This avoids recompiling the whole site when refreshing when any change is made.

Comment: Thx, i have this: <compilation debug="true" strict="false">, try now this last.

Comment: The last line helped me something, but DevTools gave me the complete solution, thanks to all.

Comment: @VictorGlez what solution did you find in DevTools?